# How to measure uncertainty and account for spatial bias when conducting ROC analysis on image data?

Tags: bias, roc, uncertainty, image-segmentation

I have a task where I need to perform ROC analysis and measure the AUC of the ROC curve, but the data is image data.

I have pairs of images (which contain real-valued pixels) and masks (which contain 0 or 1, if the pixel is negative or positive, respectively).

I have measured AUC using standard tools (sklearn), however I am aware that there are biases in this measurement because:

1- I have no notion of uncertainty around the AUC number.

2- I know that neighbourhood pixels are correlated because of spatial proximity.

The ROC-AUC metric expects the score/label pairs to be independent from each other, so I need to account for the fact that they aren't, which could be introducing a bias to the AUC I am measuring.

However, I have little idea on how to proceed, and I am unable to find the proper keywords - for some reason, using what I described isn't yielding much progress.

---

Here's my attempts. Please tell me if I am in the right direction:

1- For this problem, I may be able to use bootstrapping to get a notion of uncertainty around AUC. But how to define number of boostrapping samples?

2- I have read that you can account for autocorrelations by modelling behaviour using regression predicting the score given a set of neighbourhood voxels, then applying this regressor on the entire data and considering the predicted scores to be independentent from each other. Does this make any sense?

---

What am I missing here?

Cheers!!